# How does :nth-child work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<h1>Boxes</h1>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

I expect the `div` with the contents `1st` to be selected, but that's not the case. If, however, I remove the `h1` element, then it works as expected. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having is the selector itself: `:nth-child()`; this finds the element to which it's attached, the `div` which is the nth-child of its parent.

As you're selecting:

```
div:nth-child(1) {
 /*...*/
}
```

This won't match anything; since the `h1` element is the first-child/`:nth-child(1)` of the shared parent.

To adapt, you need to use either:

```
div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;  
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5GekP/).

Or create a new parent to enclose the `div` elements.

```
<h1>Boxes</h1>
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5GekP/1/).

In supporting browsers, you could also use `:nth-of-type(1)`:

```
div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: red;  
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5GekP/2/).

References:

- [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-of-type).

Comment: Ok what if I am not sure of the siblings and I just want the `:nth-child` to work on `div` ignoring others?

Comment: See the updated answer, `:nth-of-type()` might be your friend (but its implementation/compatibility is variable)

Comment: I dunno, somebody seems jealous that you got the mark. Anyway, even if you don't use a selector library, browser support for `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` (and in fact, *all* CSS3 structural pseudo-classes) is identical.

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't think it's jealousy (the down-vote came before the acceptance), I think it's people that just don't understand how the `:nth-child()` selector works (see the double-downvote that Praveen got). And thanks! Somehow I'd not realised that.